# Unable to import projects into E(fx)clipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-2

I am a beginner to JavaFX 2.0. I am using `Pro JavaFX 2: Definitive Guide` by `Apress`. WHen I download the code and try to import it into Eclipse, I get an error that there are no projects to import.

I tried every possible way, using an archive, via file system, etc.

However, nothing seems to help.

Here are the code downloads: http://www.apress.com/9781430268727

Will someone please help me sort it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is not organized as Eclipse projects so you can not import them. Create new projects and copy the sources from the Explorer

Comment: I figured that out after I posted this question :p

Answer (score 2):

Those sources are IDE agnostic. You can either:

- Use Eclipse: install the Java FX plugin from [here](http://download.java.net/general/javafx/eclipse/tutorial.html). Also note that on that page it tells you how to make a new Java FX project. Follow those steps and either: add the sources to your new projects afterwards or, right when you create it, chose as location the location of your sources
- Use NetBeans IDE. You can download it from [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html). [It support Java FX out of the box](https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-client/javafx.html). A tutorial on how to create a Java FX project with it can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm).

Comment: I am using e(fx)clipse :-)

Comment: @LittleChild, right, sorry, I missed that. My answer still applies, though. Just replace "Use Eclipse: install the Java FX plugin from here." by "Use E(fx)clipse".